# HTML to RST converter

Tags: html, xml, scikit-learn, restructuredtext

I have a lot of RST (reStructuredText) files converted to HTML using docutils.
Using a small developed JS app (a basic iframe with HTML5 contenteditable attribute), non-tech people can easily edit the generated HTML page. The goal would be apply the modification done in HTML back into the original RST file.

I'm wondering if there is a way to train an algorithm with the ground-truth of original_RST -> outputed_HTML conversion so we can later reverse outputed_HTML+minor modification back to RST ? What kind of algorithm will it be ? Which way should I start digging ?

To simplify the problem, instead of RST, I can also use the internal XML AST representation of docutils as document input (RST to XML-AST: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/tools/quicktest.py) and later, fix the xml2rst+xslt project (http://www.merten-home.de/FreeSoftware/xml2rst/)

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Sorry that it doesn't answer your question, but I think that user-generated html is very bad from security point of view. Define what areas should be editable by a user, and work with that specific data (containing no raw html).

Answer (score 4):

Try [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)

> If you need to convert files from one markup format into another, pandoc is your swiss-army knife.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that for a program documentation xml file generated by Sphinx, but it leaves a lot of .. raw:: html samples.

Comment: Also it ignores xml:space="preserve" markup, and make all my code one-liners. It destroys emphasis tags (which should become * in rst). I heard about pandoc, but it seems that it's a rather weak solution.